# Get src of a link jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I have div in which I have added 5 files, using appendTo, Now I want to get the src of all these files.  How do I go about getting it using jQuery. can I use .get()?

Thanks
Jean

[edit]

```
<div id="some">
<img src="jquery_book.jpg"><a href="jquery.pdf">JQuery Book</a>
</div>
```

I need src and href.

Comment: could you please post some code?

Comment: Can you post your HTML markup?

Comment: @rahul @.j
posted the html code

Answer (score 3):

Something like

```
var arrsource = new Array();

$("#yourdivid a").each(function(){
    arrSource.push ( $(this).attr("href") );    
});
```

Not using an array

```
$("#yourdivid a").each(function(){
    var currentElemSource =  $(this).attr("href");     
    // write your code here 
});
```

***Edit***

```
$("#some a").each(function(){
    var currentElem = $(this);
    var imageSource = currentElem.prev().attr("src");
    var path = currentElem.attr("href");
});
```

I assumed you are using anchor tags and you have got the path in href.

Comment: Is it necessary to use an array?

Comment: This will get all your source path in an array, and you can iterate through the array and take individual values. If you don't want to use an array then do your manipulations inside itself. Updated the answer

Comment: I am triggering the even and appending a div for test purpose

('#some1').appendTo('#div_id).attr(src);

Or is it wrong?

Comment: Will there be divs with ids some1, some2 etc

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you meant by the **file** but you can get **attribute** like this:

```
$("selector").attr('src');
```

**Based On Your Updated Answer:**

```
$('#some a').each(function(){
    alert ($(this).attr('href'));
});
```